# In windows 7 (Enterprise) the computer name is cut to 4 letters by the OS

Tags: windows-7, networking

In windows 7 (Enterprise) I set the computer name to `venusl22` and the
primary DNS suffix to `dev.halumini.com`.

But the OS automatically cut the computer name to `venu` and the hostname becomes `venu.dev.halumini.com`.

I disabled `netbios` (read something a netbios limitation) changed back to `venusl22`.

The OS asked to restart. I restarted but after restart, a shutdown was automatically done, and the name was changed back to `venu`. This creates a problem and the computer is not properlly identified by other machines.

How can I for the OS to not cut, and keep the hostname I set thru computer name and DNS.

I don't have this problems in Linux.

Comment: The NetBIOS hostname limit is either 11 or 15 characters -- I forgot which, but it is definitely not 4.

Comment: How is the DNS server configured? It may have something to do with the name getting changed.

Comment: I don't have access to DNS server configuration, but the hostname works ok, in Linux(different distributions).